# How to print the even-indexed and odd-indexed characters of strings?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexing

Task at hand:

> Given a string, S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print
>   its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated
>   strings on a single line.
>
> The test cases are written such that The first line contains an
>   integer, N (the number of test cases). Each line i of the N subsequent
>   lines contain a String.

Here is my code:

```
N = int(raw_input())

for i in range(0,N):
    string = raw_input()

evenlist = []
oddlist = []

for item, char in enumerate(strg):
    if item % 2 == 0:
        evenlist.append(char)
    else:
        oddlist.append(char)

print ''.join(evenlist), ''.join(oddlist)
```

Sample run:

```
The first input is:
2
Hacker
Rank

Expected output is:
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

But I get:

```
HceRn akrak
```

Here is a link to the [assignment](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop) that might explain the question better.

Comment: and what is the issue?

Comment: Here is a link that might explain the question better: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the error you posted. It looks like you retyped it from memory, producing code with an entirely different set of problems. Don't retype - always copy-paste.

Comment: got it. i copied and pasted

Comment: Now that you put the correct code can you tell us what the specific problem is.

Comment: Based on my understanding of HackerRank platform; you current indentation is wrong. Your current code starting from `evenlist = []` should be indented inside the first `for` loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simpler way to achieve this is via using *string slicing*:

```
>>> my_str = 'Hacker'
>>> '{} {}'.format(my_str[::2], my_str[1::2])
'Hce akr'
```

Hence, your entire code could be written as:

```
for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    my_str = raw_input()
    print '{} {}'.format(my_str[::2], my_str[1::2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do, also, something like this:

```
inp = raw_input("Enter your input: ")

final = "{}  {}".format("".join(inp[k] for k in range(len(inp)) if k % 2 == 0), "".join(inp[k] for k in range(len(inp)) if k % 2 != 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python-3

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    STDIN = input()
    print(f"{STDIN[::2]} {STDIN[1::2]}")
```

input:

```
 2
 Hacker
 Rank
```

Output:

Hce akr
Rn ak

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
N = int(input())

evenlist = [] oddlist = []

for i in range(0,N): 
   string=input() 
   evenlist.clear() 
   oddlist.clear() 
   for item, char in enumerate(string): 
     if item % 2 == 0: 
       evenlist.append(char) 
     else: oddlist.append(char) 
   print(''.join(evenlist),''.join(oddlist))

print('')
```

Comment: this code quite simple to understand try this u ill get expected output

Comment: the 1st for loop is for taking inputs.as mentioned as above expected o/p haker 1st we are making oddlist and evenlist clear then enumerate give us index and value of haker like 1 h 2 a 3 k 4 e 5 r so iteam contains index and char contains so using modules we can seperate odd and even occurences then print the output and inner for loop ends and again it enters to outer for loop so their again clear odd and even list clear then again it keeps on repeating as mentiond above thank you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the Hacker Rank problem is using string slicing and list.

```
n= int(input())
r = []
if(n>=1 and n<= 10):
    for i in range(n):
        r.append(input())
for s in r:
    print("{} {}".format(s[::2],s[1::2]))
```

Comment: Please try to edit your answer to include information on why this will answer the question rather than just providing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input())
mylist = []

for words in range (num):
    words = input()
    mylist.append(words)
#print(mylist)

i=0
#Considering 0th position as even place here.
while i<len(mylist):
    print("Letters at even places = {} Letters at odd places ={}".
      format(mylist[i][0:len(mylist[i]):2], mylist[i][1:len(mylist[i]):2]))
    i+=1
```

This is a python solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=int(input("enter number "))
for i in range(1,t+1) :
    s=input("String")
    even=[]
    odd=[]
    for j,char in enumerate(s) :
        if j%2==0:
            even.append(char)
        else:
            odd.append(char)
   print(''.join(even), ''.join(odd))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    s = input()
    idx = 0
    newstr = ''
    newstr2 = ''
    for letter in s:
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            newstr = newstr + s[idx]
        else:
            newstr2 = newstr2 + s[idx]
        idx += 1
    print(newstr, newstr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
for t in range(int(input())):
    S = input()
    y = len(S)

    print(S[i:y+1:2],S[i+1:y+1:2] )


#output= "satisfies all the test cases of HackerRank...."
```

Answer (score 0):

#using for loop and conditional statement

```
text=input()
for items in range(len(text)):
    if items%2==0:
        print(text[items],end='')
print(end='  ')
for items in range(len(text)):
    if items%2!=0:
        print(text[items],end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
N = int(input())
for _ in range(0,N):
    my_str = input()
    print ('{} {}'.format(my_str[::2], my_str[1::2]))
```

#use this , this will perfectly work for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new bee in coding but this is working well with all test cases solved.

```
T=int(input())
for i in range(T):
  S=input("")
  for item in range(length(S)):
     if item%2==0:
       print(S[item],end="")
  print(end=" ")
  for item in range(length(S)):
     if item%2!=0:
       print(S[item],end="")
  print(end='\n')
```

Comment: `length` should be `len`

Answer (score 0):

This also can do by just concatenating the words

```
Num_set = int(input())


for item in range(Num_set):
    word = input()
    new = ""
    second = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
    
        if i%2 == 0:
            new = new + word[i] 
        else:
            second = second +word[i]
    print(new +" "+second)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {


        private static void f(String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            char c[]=s.toCharArray();
            int i,j;

           for (i = 0; i <c.length;i++)
           { 
               System.out.print(c[i]);
                   i+=1;
                  // System.out.print(" ");
           }
           System.out.print(" ");

           for (j = 1; j<c.length;j++)
           {
               System.out.print(c[j]);
               j+=1;    
           }

        }

       public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
           int s=sc.nextInt();
           String s1=sc.next();
           f(s1);

            String s2=sc.next();
           System.out.println();
           f(s2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try the below algorithm. It is in Java. However the basic procedure is to 
scan the input word string along its length in increments of 2. The even 
index characters are printed first using a for loop starting with i = 0 and 
by adding an additional i++ inside the loop. The odd 
characters are printed starting the for loop from 1 and incrementing by steps 
of 2.  

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
   
    for(int iter= 1;iter<=n;iter++)
    {
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        String myString = scanner.nextLine();
        char[] myCharArray = myString.toCharArray();
        int t = myString.length();
                       
            for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
                {
                    // Print each sequential character on the same line
                    System.out.print(myCharArray[i]); 
                    i++;
                }

            System.out.print(" "); 

            for(int k = 1; k < t; k++)
                {
                    // Print each sequential character on the same line
                    System.out.print(myCharArray[k]);
                    k++; 
                }
     
        System.out.print("\n");
    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: OP question was in Python, I assume he is looking for answers in Python. Also, you may want to add some comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int T=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
            str=s.next();
          char c[]=str.toCharArray();
          int j,k;
          for(j=0;j<c.length;j++){
              System.out.print(c[j]);
              j+=1;
          }
          System.out.print(" ");
          for(k=1;k<c.length;k++){
              System.out.print(c[k]);
                k+=1;
          }
          System.out.println();
          }

        s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

//In java just to update the above answer for multiple strings they have not added for  // loop

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class dummy {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter the number of test cases :");

         int s=sc.nextInt();

         //for loop for multiple strings as per the input
         for(int m=1;m<= s;m++)
         {
              System.out.print("\n Enter the string : ");       
              String s1=sc.next();
              f(s1); 
              System.out.print();       

         }

    }

    private static void f(String s1){

            char c[]=s1.toCharArray();
            int i,j;

           for (i = 0; i <c.length;i++)
           { 
               System.out.print(c[i]);
                   i+=1;
           }
           System.out.print(" ");

           for (j = 1; j<c.length;j++)
           {
               System.out.print(c[j]);
               j+=1;    
           }
        }

}
```